# Gyroscope noise specifications from datasheet

Tags: noise, datasheet

I am comparing the gyroscopes of two IMU sensors, the BMI088 and BMI270.

BMI088 says this:

[image]

BMI270 says this:

[image]

I don't understand how to compare these numbers. Does the 0.014 get multiplied by the 0.1?

Also it seems like this is measured AFTER applying certain DLPF, is that correct?

Is it possible to determine from these numbers if one of the sensors is overall more or less noisy than the other?

Comment: No, it gets multiplied by sqrt(BW), i.e. sqrt(47) in the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specs are formatted differently and use different bandwidths, but you can compare apples-to-apples, i.e. the basic noise densities in dps/√Hz, as below:

- The BMI088 spec: 0.014 dps/√Hz (no mode specified)
- The BMI270 spec: 0.010 dps/√Hz (normal mode)
- The BMI270 spec: 0.007 dps/√Hz (performance mode)

Those theoretical noise densities begin as actual measurements using a given bandwidth. The two chips use different bandwidths (47 Hz and 74.6 Hz) for the test, and the noise level will naturally be lower in the narrower bandwidth, which was used in the BMI088 test. But at comparable bandwidths, the BMI270 has lower noise if you believe the spec.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the explanation.  It does seem like the BMI270 has lower noise than the BMI088.  What I am confused about is that Bosch seem to indicate that the BMI088 is more "robust" and desirable for robotics and drones, but the BMI270 seems better on paper, so I don't understand?  Here are the links: https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/motion-sensors/imus/bmi088/ and https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/motion-sensors/imus/bmi270/

Comment: @CaptainCodeman The datasheet shows the BMI088 has a higher maximum g-force measurement, which suggests the MEMS sensor is sturdier, and is designed for drones. The other one is for "wearables".  People don't vibrate like a drone. Choose the chip designed for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously want to compare noise levels of rotation speed output signals. That 0.1 degrees per second rms noise is a quick to see calculated value. It has been calculated by multiplying the (more informative) noise density 0.014 degrees per second per squarerot of Hz with the squareroot of signal bandwidth which is 47 Hz just for this quick reference table. I guess 47 Hz is seen to be somehow typical.

To compare the noise levels of different sensors you should compare the noise densities or at first calculate degrees per second rms values with the same bandwidth and compare them.

It's useless to have higher bandwidth than the specified output bandwidth. You can reduce it in your signal processing but you cannot make it higher.

Answer (score 1):

The figures that are in degrees per second per root Hz (the \$0.014^\circ/\mathrm s/\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}\$ and the \$\mathrm{dps}/\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}\$ are noise spectral densities -- they're not how much noise that you'll *see*, but they let you calculate how much noise you'll see in your algorithms.

The figures that are in degrees per second are *after filtering*.  Basically, they are measurable quantities, but can be deceptive if the gyro noise isn't flat across the spectrum.

Usually the lower noise density is better, as long as the bandwidth is what you need.  Someone might try to make an IMU *look* better by giving you the noise figure in degrees per second with a really narrow filter -- you need to be aware of that, and be ready to whip out your calculator and do some math.